# how to add url to bookmark with localStorage Ionic

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic-framework, bookmarks

i have a problem with ionic2 + angular ts + wordpress to create bookmark page.
i dont understand, how to put current url of page, and then i want to assign url to localstorage so i can create bookmark of page. 
anyone can help ?

i have searching about this problem about 3 days, but i get nothing.

to get url i try with this code and test on console.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-favorites',
  templateUrl: 'favorites.html',
})
export class FavoritesPage {
  url:string = this.navParams.get('url');
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
  ){
      console.log(this.url);
    }
```

the console say undefined

Comment: Have you tried putting `console.log(navParams.get('url'));` instead? What does that do?

Comment: @Adam yes i have, at the console.log(navParams.get('url')); //undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's hard to give suggestions based on the information you give. What URL are you trying to save to your favourites?

`navParams.get()` gets the parameters you passed when opening that page.

As an example, let's say you have a "Home" page and a "Favourites" page. When your app loads you see the home page. You can then add a link to the favourites page and pass it a parameter like that:

```
let data = 'test';
this.navCtrl.push(FavouritesPage, {
  data: data
});
```

You can then get the value of the data parameter on the FavouritesPage like that:

```
constructor(...) {
  this.navParams.get('data'); // This will be 'test'
}
```

You said that you work with Wordpress. So somewhere you will have a URL like "https://example.com/my/path/" or a unique ID. You need to pass that URL to the favourites page as described above. Or if you are trying to favourite a page in your app, I would instead pass a unique name and then use that name to open the according page (using an if/else).

Comment: i got it. it's very helpful.
but, can i use localStorage?
`window.localStorage.getItem()` or `localStorage.getItem()` ? and then , let's say i want to put `localStorage.setItem()` in index.ts, then i want to `localStorage.getItem()` in favorite.ts to get item for according list in favorite page. can i ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use "window.location".

the navParams is to pass parameters between the views.

Comment: i tried putting `console.log(window.location);` console output localhost, cause of android emulator inspect at the browser i use to be at localhost. how can i get the post url with `window.location` ?

Comment: check this:   https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-current-page-name/52993